# Completely lost with C++ (First week learning)

Tags: c++

I just started learning C++ in my Into to C++ class. My professor is not in the slightest bit helpful or return emailed questions. So here I am , looking for help on my first assignment.

I truly want to learn, and don't want anyone "doing" my assignment for me, but I desperately need help trying to figure out where I am going wrong, what am I missing, etc?

The program parameters of the lab assignment are:

- Must prompt for the name of the gaming programs, and their prices.
- Next, it must compute the total payment price that includes a tax of 8.50%
- Then compute a discount payment price that is 25% off the original items price.
- Output the appropriate results for the total and discount payments.

Here is the code I am trying and it builds/compiles? but won't function the way I want it to.

[Picture of what I am trying](https://i.stack.imgur.com/45R1h.png)

Comment: You'd better add code as text.

Comment: Always try to add code as text not as picture

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Must prompt for the name of the gaming programs, and their prices.

You want to input the name of the games, so you must be reading the input into a string and not int datatype as you did in your program. Just change the variable `a`, `c`, `e` to the datatype `string` instead of `int` and your program would run fine.

---

> Next, it must compute the total payment price that includes a tax of 8.50%

Here you must be adding a tax amount of 8.50% to each of the game titles. It should be done as -

```
total = ( b+( b*0.085 ) ) + ( d+( d*0.085 ) ) + ( f+( f*0.085 ) ) ;
```

You are probably wrongly subtracting it. I don't know if you were meant to calculate the prices after deducting the taxes. If this was case, the subtraction like  `b -(b*.85)` would be correct.

But, your statement had another error. You wrote the statement as -

```
total = b -(b*.85) , d -(d*.85) , f -(f*.85);
```

which meant that total was assigned `b -(b*.85)` , and `d -(d*.85)` & `f -(f*.85)` ran as separate statements. This were the two errors I found in your code. Just replace the commas with addition `+` and your program will work.

Hope this helps !

Comment: Thank you so very much, I made the changes and it worked well.

Answer (score 2):

In the 27th line, you wrote:
`total = b - (b * .085), d - (d * .085), f - (f * .085);`

What you're doing here, actually, is not computing `total`, but assigning `b - (b * .085)` to `total`.

What you probably want to do is `total = b + (b * .085) + d + (d * .085) + f + (f * .085);`,
i.e., just replace the commas with pluses, and *ADD* the taxes rather than subtracting them, and you'll be fine.

Also note what Abhishek told you about inputting the titles of the programs.

Comment: Thank you for the help, I appreciate it.